# RecyclerView stutters when new view added

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view which is populated dynamically from an API. The recycler view item contains an imageview with text layered over the top of it, the images for the image view come from the API and are loaded in using Picasso. When scrolling the recyclerview I have found that when a new view is added to the bottom there is a slight stutter in the scroll. I have also found that the more i scroll, the slower and less responsive the scrolling gets. I have tried using it with the picasso code commented out and get the same results.

Here is my adapter for the recyclerview:

```
public class EventListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
public ArrayList<EventObject> eventList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private String category;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView img_main;
    private RelativeLayout layoutItem;
    private TextView txt_event_name;
    private TextView txt_event_details;
    private TextView txt_going_to;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        img_main = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_main);
        txt_event_details = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_event_details);
        txt_event_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_event_name);
        txt_going_to = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_going_to);
        gradient_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gradient_view);
        layoutItem = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_event_item);
    }

    public void bindView(final Context context, final EventObject eventObject, String category) throws JSONException, ParseException {
        txt_event_name.setTypeface(FontClass.getOpenSansRegular(context));
        txt_event_details.setTypeface(FontClass.getOpenSansLight(context));
        txt_going_to.setTypeface(FontClass.getOpenSansLight(context));

        txt_event_name.setText(eventObject.getEventName());

        if (eventObject.getVenueName().contains(eventObject.getTown())) {
            txt_event_details.setText(eventObject.getVenueName() + ", " + getFormattedDate(eventObject.getEventDate()));
        } else {
            txt_event_details.setText(eventObject.getVenueName() + ", " + eventObject.getTown() + ", " + getFormattedDate(eventObject.getEventDate()));
        }

        if(eventObject.getFeeFreeStatus() == 1){
            if(category.equalsIgnoreCase("no fees")) {
                txt_going_to.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                txt_going_to.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txt_going_to.setText("Fee free tickets available");
            }

        } else if (Integer.parseInt(eventObject.getGoingToCount()) >= 200) {
            txt_going_to.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txt_going_to.setText("Popular event: " + eventObject.getGoingToCount() + " going");
        } else {
            txt_going_to.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        layoutItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((HomeActivity) context).setEventProfileFrag(eventObject.getFullJsonObject(), null);
            }
        });

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(eventObject.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.holder_image)
                .into(img_main);

    }

    private String getFormattedDate(String dateString) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.UK);
        Date newDate = format.parse(dateString);

        format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMMM", Locale.UK);
        String date = format.format(newDate);

        return date;
    }

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_event_list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    try {
        holder.bindView(context, eventList.get(position), this.category);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return eventList.size();
}


public EventListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<EventObject> eventList, String category) {
    this.context = context;
    this.eventList = eventList;
    this.category = category;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    setHasStableIds(true);
}

public void addItems(ArrayList<EventObject> eventList) {
    this.eventList.addAll(eventList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Comment: try without using setTypeface it get more time

Comment: Thats Normal, and depends whats size are the original thumbnails and device power. You could speed it up by resizing the thumbnails on the fly to the exact size on the items ItemImageView  https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit . Can you confirm that when the items Load in as you scroll down and then you scroll up the list Feels faster and more fluid?? This is because Picasso loads the Thumbs from Cache instead of the internet

Comment: Add the layout you are Inflating for your items in your Q. That could be an issue too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reasons that might you experience stuttering:

1. You are (probably) deserializing data inside the adapter. You shouldn't, deserialzing could be expensive process. Get rid of deserilization inside onBindViewHolder, send model objects deserialized.

```
try {
        holder.bindView(context, eventList.get(position), this.category);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

2. Don't force RecyclerView.Adapter to attempt to redraw all items when not needed. Improve this and use `notifyItemXXXX()` or `notifyItemRangeXXX()` methods :

```
public void addItems(ArrayList eventList) {
    this.eventList.addAll(eventList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

3. Parse dates and primitives when you are deserilizing the data (but not inside `onBindViewHolder()` deserilization)
4. Try to set typeface differently, like providing it in your xml. Cache fonts.
5. `.contains()` could be slow for long strings

Comment: Can you give an example of how to improve the code in the question?